# Method <NSURLSessionDelegate> is not called, when no internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using NSURLSessionDownloadTask and NSURLSession.
Question:

When I started downloading and after a while Internet is turned off, which method from  or  must be called ?

P.S. 
At the moment, does not call the method.
I want get call in delegate’s method with error and display on screen some message -@“You lost internet connection”.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful !
If you test on a simulator and disable wifi on a mac, the method will not be called.
Test only on a real device

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

from `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`.

And it's true - this method is called when Internet connection disappear only on the real device. On simulator task is paused and resume when Internet connection get back.